# Meta-description not found in tools.seochat.com: "ERROR! No description data found"

Tags: meta-description, tools

I was using http://tools.seochat.com/tools/search-spider-simulator to check what the crawler see and get from my website, but when I check my website, it says:

> ERROR!
>   No description data found

But I have in my HTML a `meta`-`description` in the `head` which is written like this

```html
<meta id="meta-description" name="description" content="The Description Of My Page" />
```

Why is it that the tools says "Error! No description data found" when in my HTML I've put the `meta`-`description` in the `head`?

Comment: Usual case of taking SEO suggestions with a grain of salt until verified by other sources. Attribute "id=" does not belong in a header meta tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a better answer.

```
<meta name="description" content="The Description Of My Page">
```

I see no point in having ID parameter in the meta tag because no value in the meta tags will be changed by javascript, and if they are expected to, then there is something wrong with your webpage.

Also, this answer saves you about 20 bytes which means your webpage will load a tiny bit faster. You'll save more bytes if you remove the ID parameter of all the tags that you don't plan to alter other values of in javascript.

Comment: Mike! Damned if the simplest things don't always come to mind. You are exactly right about the id. It is in the bloody header!! What would be the point? On up-vote my friend.

Comment: Not only is the `id` attribute unnecessary, it is also invalid - `meta` elements do not have `id` attributes. However, I don't think real search engines would be so strict - they cope perfectly well with a mountain of invalid HTML (unless this is true XHTML?). But since it is invalid it is down to the "parser" to decide what to do with it.

Comment: Mizone, run your HTML through http://validator.w3.org/ to see the errors it produces. It will save you a heart ache.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to this:

```
<meta name="description" id="meta-description" content="The Description Of My Page" />
```

If that does not work, then try this:

```
<meta name="description" id="meta-description" content="The Description Of My Page">
```

It is possible that the agent is hard-wired to expect things a certain way as a parser.